# My ReportViewer doesn't show anything after I published my site?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using reportviewer in my site with asp.net vb 
After I published my site, my ReportViewer doesn't show anything!!!
why? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Verify that the handlers and the modules for report viewer are correctly configured in web.config. From IIS version 7.0 modules and handlers are registered under system.webserver element.

Comment: @Mihir could you explain to me how to Verify that the handlers and the modules for report viewer are correctly configured in web.config???
in my web.config file its written
<add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to verify that the resources needed by report viewer are resolved with the help of fiddler or developer tools.

If requests to the report viewer are ending up with error or 404 then there is definitely an issue with the registration of report viewer handler in config file.

You can refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251661.aspx) in httpHandlers section of the documentation to correctly configure handlers in config file.

Comment: #Mihir thank you It works now I edit web.config file with assemblies by delete all assemblies except reportviewer

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same thing and I had the same problem. I fixed it by setting  AsyncRendering to false.

I hope it helps,

Regards.